# railsinstaller.org website was not found, what do I do now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I'm taking a course on Ruby on Rails. In the video the instructor recommends that you use
railsinstaller.org to download Rails instead of rubyonrails.org .  But the site isn't there.

According to whois, it is inactive.
(When I investigated I got farther, but then got SSL errors. See solution below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My instructor said to go to this website for instructions. This solution also works if you are getting SSL errors when trying to use Ruby On Rails ( See Note1 and Note2 below first):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iF8caVyDi5g&list=PLCC34OHNcOtrk3BDsfZwf4GattdLoKCOF&index=1&t=839s

Note1:
... get installer from here (If you have Git already, unclick that box.):
https://web.archive.org/web/20210306035811/http://railsinstaller.org/en

The idea is to remove ruby and rails from your machine. (Make sure you have node and yarn.)  Run the installer.  Then install newest stable versions of Ruby and Rails. Installing Ruby from rubyinstaller.org

Note2:  Instead of using "gem install rails" command as Youtube video says, Do the following:

(thanks to Kingston Peng for this process)

"Run the command:
$ gem install gemName  --source http://rubygems.org
it worked for me. I got: "1 gem installed".

So I tried:
$ gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
", said Kingston Peng.

It worked!  "37 gems installed"!

Answer (score 0):

The [GoRails setup guide](https://gorails.com/setup) is a good resource for this. This will show you how to download the latest versions of Ruby and Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same course by the same instructor. Also, [railsinstaller.org](https://railsinstaller.org) isn't working, so, you may use the link mentioned below to directly install the same version of ruby rails.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-3.4.0.exe